# Solve Linq expression using Distinct, GroupBy and Take

Tags: linq, lambda

I am using Entity Framework, working with lambda expressions, I have to select number of selected records from the grid (_numRecords) which includes sorting, remove duplicates based on a column (Distinct by a column). Following is the code:

```
private IEnumerable<ReadViewModel> generateLocalData(IQueryable<ReadViewModel> query, [DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest dsRequest, int exportXml)
{
    if (exportXml > 0)
        query = query.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault());
    //query = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.EventDate).GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault());
    //query = query.DistinctBy(x => x.Id).AsQueryable<ReadViewModel>();

    query = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.EventDate);
    query = query.ApplySorting(dsRequest.Groups, dsRequest.Sorts);
    query = query.Take(this._numRecords);

    List<ReadViewModel> data;
    data = query.ToList();

    return data;
}

public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    HashSet<TKey> knownKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();
    foreach (TSource element in source)
    {
        if (knownKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
        {
            yield return element;
        }
    }
}
```

There is data on the grid (which can have duplicate Id field) but when I export it to xml, it should be unique.

Problem is when Distinct is applied to lambda expression it destroys the sorting, and I am using Take() method so I need to use it before fetching data from DB.

I've used 2 approaches to acheive distinct: by GroupBy & Single/Select and DistinctBy from Extension methods. But I'm unable to make it work, using these methods, as sorting is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static IQueryable<T> DistinctBy<T, TKey>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, TKey>> keySelector)
{
   return source.GroupBy(keySelector).Select(grp => grp.First());
}
```

Group by the key you want to be distinct by, then take the first item from each group. You might need `FirstOrDefault()` with some providers that don't do well with `First()` within queries.

This is sub-optimal when used with linq-to-objects, but you have the optimal approach for that case in your question already.

Comment: How would the expression go about ?
We are using Expression<>

Comment: The same lambda that worked as the Func in the enumerable version should work; `x => x.Id`.